# Python-for-android android billing

Tags: python, android, kivy, in-app-billing

I want to implement in-app billing like this: https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/stable/old_toolchain/android/
The program crashes at the very beginning - at the first string of the code

```
from android.billing import BillingService
```

The appropriate logcat entry:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'BillingService' from 'android.billing'
```

Moreover, it seems that buildozer ignores --with--billing option when I run it as in manual:
buildozer android release --with-billing $BILLING_PUBKEY
it says "Unknown command ...." and types all BILLING_PUBKEY content.
As a matter of fact my app is Kivy-based. Does anybody knows any suitable method/library to have in-app-purchases?

Answer (score 0):

That doc page is from the archived documentation of the old python-for-android toolchain, which ceased to be supported several years ago. It's quite possible that the billing method it used is also out of date on the java side.

As it stands we have no built-in support for in-app purchases. I understand it's possible to add it, but to do so requires reading the java docs and understanding how to integrate that into python-for-android's templates and your python code.